# Use "COLUMN" function on imported range Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find the location of the last non-empty cell in a row in a Google Sheet, and I've found several methods, but have been struggling to get any to work on imported data. I need to perform this function on a row in a different tab.

Can I use some variation of this method:

=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(A2:2)*(--(A2:2<>""))))

on a range in a different tab? When I try using importrange in lieu of the ranges provided above, I get the error "Argument must be a range".

Here's what I'm trying

=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(IMPORTRANGE("URL","tab!A2:2"))*(--( IMPORTRANGE("URL","tab!A2:2")<>""))))

Do I have a syntax error? Or can I not use a function like "COLUMN" on an imported range? Any ideas of a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=counta(importrange("URL","tab!A2:2"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned over the weekend why my original attempt isn't workable (because import range returns an array rather than a range). I will try this and see if it works for my case.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. But how might I use the counta function to tell me what is the last column that isn't empty in a given range, where some columns are empty?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=MAX(INDEX(IF(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "tab!A2:2")="",, SEQUENCE(1, 10000)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Tbh, I don't fully understand how this is working, but it appears to do the trick.